# Getting interpolated values to show after remove and re-add to DOM for Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I'm allowing a component (layout-panel) to be removed and then (later) re-added to the DOM using the following code:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngIf="item.isVisible && idx > 0" [colspan]="columns > item.colSpan ? item.colSpan : columns" [rowspan]="item.rowSpan">
  <mat-card *ngIf="layout.useCard && item.isVisible" [ngStyle]="item.tileStyles">
    <layout-panel [panelView]="item"></layout-panel>
  </mat-card>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Initially, item.isVisible is true and interpolated values show up on the form. Then I set item.isVisible to false and then set it back to true again. Now, the interpolated values in the layout panel are no longer visible. This is true even though the layout-panel properties still have values. How can I get these values to show once again?

Comment: it should show up if items does indeed contain a list of items. Has layout.useCard changed or anything else that may cause it not to show.

Comment: @TaranjitKang - Nothing has changed. The card shows up, just the data on the card is missing.